# Next and Previous to navigate text fields

Tags: iphone

I have a sign-up form in my application with several UITextFields.  In order to speed up the process I would like to add a next and previous button to a toolbar pinned above the keyboard and allow the user to "tab" between the fields using these buttons.

I know I can navigate through the subviews collection on my view, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this?

This functionality is implemented in safari as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add this type of functionality to your app, you need to create a custom view with the next/previous buttons and position it properly when the keyboard appears. Then handle any touches to those buttons.

Comment: Yeah ... that part is easy...
I'm asking what the code in the Next handler needs to be...